# Javascript bar chart, where bar is split into triangles

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, chart.js

I am having kinda a hard time to find a solution for a special type of bar chart.

The graph:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIHWz.png

After a long time of searching the web, I wasn't able to find a good solution for this. I was using chart.js and the first thing I tried was to fill a bar with .svg, but sadly it is possible to fill it only with pattern. Another thing I thought may work was to design my own bar via two separate stacked line graphs, but there I wasn't successful becouse of the dependency on xAxis (to create a triangle I would need three labels, and the result was still total ****).

I would really appreciate if anybody would be helpful and suggest an idea how to go around this as I am absoulutely out of ideas.

Comment: why not use stacked bar chart? The only difference is the horizontal line instead of diagonal line

Comment: Yea, that is kinda an easy solution, but as this is something that a designer made as a design I am trying to first find a solution to replicate it as closely as possible. If everything fails I guess I will go with the stacked bar.

Comment: Well you either change library or modify the stacked bar code from chartjs to draw using triangle instead of rectangle

Comment: Well since I already searched the web for a different library and I don't think I have enough experience nor time to change the library, I guess the stacked bar will have to do it.